# Check whitespaces and remove in the First Name Customer Registration in FE, BE

Tags: magento2, admin, customer

Once a new customer is being registered and Add New Customer in Admin the extension checks the First Name field. If the First Name field has whitespaces, they must be removed, so the customer entity is saved without whitespaces in the First Name property. All checks and modifications must be performed on the server side.

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new module and use `plugin` to achieve your requirement.
Assume the Vendor name is `TuVan` and the module name is `Customer`, take the following steps:

Step 1: Create `app/code/TuVan/Customer/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'TuVan_Customer', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create `app/code/TuVan/Customer/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TuVan_Customer">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create `app/code/TuVan/Customer/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
        <plugin name="RemoveFirstNameWhiteSpace" type="TuVan\Customer\Plugin\RemoveFirstNameWhiteSpace"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 4: Create `app/code/TuVan/Customer/Plugin/RemoveFirstNameWhiteSpace.php`

```
<?php

namespace TuVan\Customer\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;

class RemoveFirstNameWhiteSpace
{
    public function beforeSave(CustomerRepository $subject, CustomerInterface $customer, $passwordHash = null)
    {
    // Only apply to the new customer
    if (!$customer->getId() && $firstName = $customer->getFirstName()) {
        $firstName = str_replace(' ', '', $firstName);
        $customer->setFirstName($firstName);
    }

     return [$customer, $passwordHash];   
    }
}
```

Step 5: Run setup upgrade command to install and enable the module:

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Step 6: Run compilation code command:
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Step 7: Run deploy static content command:
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You are done.

Comment: You helped me very much. Thanks and Best regards :)))

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!

Comment: That would be great if you click the Up button at the top-left corner of my answer to upvote the answer. That means my answer is useful.

Comment: Thanks and see you again !!!